# I want to delete the first n entries in a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file, when I import it into pandas I have

```
Index        DATE_TIME            Parameter
0         13/1/2016 03.45            0
1         13/1/2016 04.45            13
2         13/1/2016 05.00           27.6
3         13/1/2016 06.45            0
4         13/1/2016 07.00            1
```

I want to delete the first 1000 entries from the parameters column without deleting the DATE_TIME column, leaving the top part of parameter blank.

This is probably really simple but I can't seem to find the right command.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: I meant I'm hunting through the pandas documentation looking for something that can do this. Usually I have just had to delete the top n rows from an entire dataframe, which is easier, by cutting it with ix. or dropping columns, or filling N/As. this time I need to edit one column while keeping the other intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `loc` and passing the first N entries from the index:

```
In [120]:
df.loc[df.index[:2], 'Parameter'] = np.NaN
df

Out[120]:
       Index  DATE_TIME  Parameter
0  13/1/2016       3.45        NaN
1  13/1/2016       4.45        NaN
2  13/1/2016       5.00       27.6
3  13/1/2016       6.45        0.0
4  13/1/2016       7.00        1.0
```

This will operate on a view rather than a copy

You assign whatever value you wish, here I assign `NaN`